# ReImPlot does not plot Imaginary part in Wolfram Cloud

Tags: plotting, warning-messages

Recently came across a problem: when trying to plot complex-valued function with ReImPlot in WolframCloud (free version), i get only a real part. Is this a free-version issue or something else?
[image: ReImPlot result in WolframCloud]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please post code (not images) that can be copied and pasted to reproduce the problem.

Comment: What browser/platform are you using?  I see the dotted line with Safari 14.1 on macOS.

Comment: @BrettChampion, Chrome 93.0.4577.82 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, [`ReImPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReImPlot) uses dashing for the imaginary part, and it seems that the cloud renderer can't handle dashing yet. You can try:

```
ReImPlot[
    Sqrt[(x^2-1)(x^2-4)], {x, -5, 5},
    ReImStyle->{Blue, Directive[Dashing[None], Red]}
]
```

[image]

Comment: That works. Thank you very much. Unfortunatelly, I was hoping to have a dashed line).